# Were the prosecutors involved in the final decision?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

Near the end of Molly's Game, Molly and her lawyer agree to talk with the prosecution After some malicious jabs by the prosecution, her lawyer (whose name I've already forgotten...) gives us a rousing speech about Molly's moral integrity, and the room goes quiet. The lawyers then have a private discussion while Molly leaves and ends up having a touching reunion with her father.

When Molly next meets with her lawyer, he tells her that the the court is effectively blackmailing her with jail time if she won't  release highly incriminating and embarrassing information on many innocent people, which she refuses to do. At the final hearing, Molly pleads guilty. The judge then has a private discussion with the prosecutors. After this, he declares that the court does not agree with the recommendation of the prosecution regarding Molly's sentencing, and gives her community service and probation instead.

All of this is a little fishy. Firstly, her lawyer  noted, and the prosecutors didn't disagree, that this judge has historically agreed with their recommendations. Secondly, her lawyer seemed to know, or had an idea, of what was about to happen just before the judge passes his decision.

Thus, I inferred that that the backhanded blackmail might have been a test of Molly's moral integrity intended to prove to the prosecutors what her lawyer had earlier claimed. The judge was notified beforehand of this. So, when Molly officially enters her guilty plea, the judge sees the proof and decides to reduce her sentence.

However, it isn't clear to me if the prosecutors were in on this plan, if the plan only involved the lawyer and judge, or if there was no such plan in the first place and the judge acted entirely on his own and broke with his historical trend of agreeing with the recommendation given to him.

Ultimately, who was involved in that decision?

Comment: I got the sense that the prosecution REALLY wanted the incriminating evidence on Molly's clients, but that they had a very flimsy case. They were just trying to intimidate her with trumped-up charges. It seemed as though the prosecution was **not** involved in the judge's decision, and that the judge's decision was a real blow to their ability to prosecute other people who were involved.